# Building software in docker - at `build` or at `run` time?

Tags: docker

I am currently using docker do create a reproducable build environment (for building Android ROMs). Now I would like to run multiple builds, each with slight variations. Every build contains of several steps, e.g.

1. Build Linux kernel
2. Build Android
3. Include custom apps
4. Package image

If two builds only vary at step 3, it would be great to be able to reuse the first two steps.

I am thinking of two options:

- Enter my docker container, run the build, and save the build artifacts at each step. Later check if I can reuse them. This would require quite a bit of coding, and manual management of build artifacts.
- Abuse `docker build`. Create a dockerfile for each configuration, with one `RUN` command for each step. I think this will let me use docker's caching - if two builds only differ at step 3, docker will reuse a layer containing steps 1 and 2. I would only ever "run" the container I built to copy out the finished ROM.

Is there a "best" or canonical way to do this? Is there any downside to using `docker build` in this way?

Answer (score 2):

You could build what's called a "base image", and push that up to a docker registry. Then for the two branches of that image, you use the `FROM` keyword. But, instead of using a base image like `FROM ubuntu:latest` , you use your base image:

To use the base image:

```
FROM repo/base-image:tag
```

So your base could be:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

# Step 1
COPY /tmp /tmp

# Step 2
ADD /src /src
```

You build and push that:

```
docker build -t repo/base-image .
docker push repo/base-image
```

Then, in your other two Dockerfiles...

Dockerfile1

```
FROM repo/base-image:tag

# Step 3 specific to this Dockerfile1
ADD /something /somewhere

# Do different things
EXPOSE 443
```

Dockerfile2

```
FROM repo/base-image:tag

# Step 3 specific to this Dockerfile2
ADD /something-else /somewhere-else

# Do different things
EXPOSE 80
```

That way they have the first 2 layers in common, and only differ by the third layer. The lines in docker files are called layers. Kind of like traversing a tree. The more lines you have, the more layers / levels you have. But, based on the `FROM repo/img:tag` line, this tells you where to inherit ALL previous layers from.

Comment: `FROM ubuntu/ubuntu:14:04` should be replaced with `FROM ubuntu:latest` (i.e., no slash because it is a distribution, not a mere user repo)

Comment: You're welcome. Also, regarding the tag, it should be 14.04 or 16.04 or 18.04, but not 14:04 :)

Answer (score 1):

The second option (relying on `Dockerfile`s + `docker build`) is definitely the way to go.

Indeed as you already mentioned it in your question, this will enable Docker to use caching.

Also, I recall that even if there is only one `Dockerfile` involved with a single `FROM ...` command, Docker's caching will already be active. That's the reason why in a `Dockerfile`, the order of commands matters (it is preferable to run beforehand the commands that are unlikely to change at each build, and afterwards the commands that are likely to - such as the compilation of custom apps).

You can thus follow the steps detailed in @JabariDash's answer, but if you notice that an intermediate image `repo/some-image` is only used once (via a command `FROM repo/some-image` in another `Dockerfile`), note that you can avoid defining this `repo/some-image` in a separate `Dockerfile`: indeed you can put several `FROM ...` commands in the same `Dockerfile`, and rely on the so-called [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) feature of Docker `>= 17.05`.